# Prisma MongoDB error: Type "Date" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another model, custom type, or enum

Tags: node.js, mongodb, prisma

I use "Date" in Prisma schema， as follow:

```
model User {
  id           String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  username     String
  dateOfBirth  Date
}
```

vscode gives an error:

```
Type "Date" is neither a built-in type, nor refers to another model, custom type, or enum.
```

but there is "Date" in Prisma docs: https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/database-connectors/mongodb#native-type-mapping-from-prisma-to-mongodb

[image: Snipaste_2023-11-13_12-09-19]

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some inconsistency in the prisma docs.

They mention Date as a primitive type, but in many of their examples they define dates using the `DateTime` type.

You may find these sections useful:

- [Prisma Schema Reference](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#datetime)
- [Prisma Default Type Mappings](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/other/prisma-type-system#default-type-mappings)

Here is a print from one of their examples:

[image: print]